# How to receive user-input and pass it to object?

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

I have a java program which will receive user-input and pass it an object to find the area of a circle.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Area{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
double n = reader.nextDouble(); 
   reader.close(); 
          Circle c = new Circle();
          c.radius = n;
          c.area=3.148*c.radius*c.radius;
          System.out.println(c.radius);

    }
}
class Circle {
        double radius;
       double area;

}
```

The program receives user input but it's not performing the operation. 
How to make this work

Regards

Comment: I don't see any addition.

Comment: where is the addition, I see only circle..

Comment: Are you aware that you print the radius? You probably want to display the computed area.

Comment: @davidxxx, updated

Comment: General hint: step through your application with a debugger.

Comment: @meVeekay .. updated

Comment: @Thomas .. I  tested this online compiler

Comment: you print the `radius`, not the `area`. Replace  `System.out.println(c.radius);` by `System.out.println(c.area);`

Comment: @davidxxx ..  yes.. i missed it..

Comment: Ok fine :) I vote to close the question.

Comment: Looks like you're just starting to learn OO programming. Let me take this opportunity to introduce you to [the opposing viewpoint](https://youtu.be/QM1iUe6IofM?t=1m) so you can make up your own mind about it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(c.area);
```

That should fix your problem.

Although, if I can suggest, you're better of doing these calculations in your Circle class. It's good coding practice.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   double n = reader.nextDouble();
   reader.close();
   Circle circle = new Circle(n);
   double area = circle.getArea();
   System.out.printf("The area is %f", area);
   }
}

class Circle {
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double radius) {
       this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getArea() {
       return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }
    public double getRadius() {
       return radius;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this sample implementation:

```
class Circle {

    private static final double PI = 3.148;

    private double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double calculateArea() {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input = reader.nextDouble();
        reader.close();

        Circle circle = new Circle(input);
        double area = circle.calculateArea();
        System.out.printf("My radius is %f%n", circle.getRadius());
        System.out.printf("My area is %f", area);
    }
}
```

- Your initial mistake is that you were printing `c.radius` instead of `c.area`.
- The constructor `public Circle(double radius)` makes sure that a `Circle` object always has a radius whenever one is created. A circle without a radius doesn't really make sense.
- `Circle` should be responsible for everything related to a circle. That's why the calculation of the area, a typical circle-related math operation, should be handled by `Circle` and not outside in `main()`.

Comment: Note: the constant is called "PI" and can be used to calculate the area or circumference of a [pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie). ;)

Comment: Oops, my bad. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

The operation performs well, but you just don't pass the correct argument to `System.out.println`. At the end you pass `c.radius` instead of `c.area` and the result of operation isn't written to the console. This is what you should write at the end od main method:

```
System.out.println(c.area)
```